# Trouble downloading file from browser on Android

Tags: android, browser, amazon-s3, download

I'm testing a website that's in development using my Galaxy S5. Our app exposes files on AWS S3 for download using signed urls.

Download fails in the built-in browser and Chrome, but works in Firefox (it also works in all browsers on every other platform we've tested).

The file shows up as  in my notification area even though we set the Content-Disposition like it says to here: http://www.digiblog.de/2011/04/android-and-the-download-file-headers/. The download fails after a while. Out members of my team have the same exact issue on their Android phones. Copying the URLs and pasting them directly to the address bar fails as well.

We're able to download unsigned S3 URLs, but we need the signed versions for security. Also, if instead of tapping the link to start the download, we tap+hold the link and select "Save link" from the context menu then it works (but only in Chrome, still fails in the default browser), but we can't expect customers to know to use this work around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem was our bucket names contained underscores, which aren't valid in subdomains according to the spec. The Android download manager obeys the spec, while everyone else doesn't care.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-222

Comment: You are a lifesaver, I had the same problem, thank you!