# File downloads failing on Android

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to allow users to download files from our server, and I'd like to serve these files via an ASP.NET MVC 5 controller action.  My action looks like this:

```
public FileContentResult Download(int fileId)
{
    var myContent = GetContentForFile(fileId);
    var myFileMeta = GetFileMeta(fileId);

    if (myContent == null || myFileMeta == null)
        throw new FriendlyException("The file or its associated data could not be found.");

    return File(myContent.Content, myContent.MediaType, myFileMeta.FileName);
}
```

The above is as simple as I could get it, it works fine on PC and iPhone, but not on Android.  Using Fiddler, I can see that the following response headers when I try to download one of my files - in this case a JPG file called "1447114384146-643143584.jpg":

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=1447114384146-643143584.jpg
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 12 Nov 2015 23:09:00 GMT
Content-Length: 1682868
```

Note that I don't have any reliable way to know the correct MIME-type - is this an issue and could it explain why the file isn't being downloaded in Android?

To clarify, when I attempt to download any file from the database using Android, I get a toast notification telling me "Download started", but then the download sits in the queue for a while on 0% before eventually just changing to "Failed".

**What I've tried**

I've tried all manner of things that people have suggested in similar questions, most of which are to do with the `content-disposition` header or the `content-type` header.  I've tried forcing the `content-type` header to `application/octet-stream` for every file, I've tried sending the correct `content-type` header for the particular file.  I've tried manually sending the `content-disposition` header.  I've tried forcing the filename extension to uppercase.

None of the above has worked, in fact none of them have had any impact at all on the problem, for better OR worse.  I'm amazed that this is so hard - I feel like I must be missing something obvious?

**Additional information**

- Browser: latest Chrome on Android
- OS: Android 5.1 (also occurs for a coworker on their Android phone which is at an earlier Android version (not sure which specifically), so I don't think this is tied to a specific Android version).

**Update**

After reading this blog entry: http://www.digiblog.de/2011/04/android-and-the-download-file-headers/ I tried following the advice and set my headers exactly as suggested:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="1447114384146-643143584.JPG"
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 12 Nov 2015 23:42:18 GMT
Content-Length: 1682868
```

Again, this had no impact on the problem at all.

**Futher update**

I have been able to test on a Marshmallow (Android v6.0) device and the download works.  It seems to be a pre-Marshmallow issue.

Comment: One moment, `var`?, It's Android and it's based on Java, no JavaScript

Comment: As indicated by the tags, I'm developing this in ASP.NET MVC 5. (C#)  (Added some clarification on this in the question, as I can see how it was worded confusingly).

Comment: Post your code that downloads the file.

Comment: @BNK I'm not sure what you mean - the file is downloaded by accessing the URL.  You do this in the website by clicking a link, but you can also browse  directly to the file using a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly this was caused by something very specific to my environment, but I'd like to put the answer here in case anyone else stumbles across this same problem.

It turns out the Android download manager doesn't like underscores in domain names, and our local domain address had an underscore in it.  I used the server's IP address instead and everything worked as expected.

For example this: `http://www.my_domain.com.au/file.png` won't work. This: `http://192.168.x.x/file.png` does work.

Found as an answer on this question: [Trouble downloading file from browser on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831682/trouble-downloading-file-from-browser-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** I don't have enough rep to add to the comments so I am forced to comment here.

1. Have you tried different versions of Android using the emulator or
   have you only tried using an actual device?
2. If only on a device, is the code in production or are using
   connecting to your local development system through a local wireless
   connection?
3. Have you tried to use Chrome Remote Debugging on the device?
   https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging?hl=en

As a way to rule out issues with the setup on your device would be to write a small Android app using Xamarin + RestSharp that does nothing but hits your download url to see if that works.  If it does, then that helps to point the finger at Chrome itself.  If it doesn't then at least you can run the app with the debugger attached to get better insight as to what is happening on the other end.

https://xamarin.com/

https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp

**UPDATE:** Response headers as seen by Fiddler when calling a test served by my local machine

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=profile.jpg
Date: Fri, 13 Nov 2015 02:09:23 GMT
Content-Length: 218143
```

**Update:** Here are the incoming request server variable

```
ALL_HTTP=HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL:max-age=0
HTTP_CONNECTION:keep-alive
HTTP_ACCEPT:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING:gzip, deflate, sdch
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE:en-US,en;q=0.8
HTTP_COOKIE:_ga=GA1.1.420021277.1447377172
HTTP_HOST:192.168.1.2
HTTP_USER_AGENT:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0.2; HTC One Build/LRX22G) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.76 Mobile Safari/537.36
HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS:1
HTTP_DNT:1
ALL_RAW=Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.420021277.1447377172
Host: 192.168.1.2
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0.2; HTC One Build/LRX22G) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.76 Mobile Safari/537.36
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
DNT: 1
APPL_MD_PATH=/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT
APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH=C:\development\rumble-strip\projects\net-framework\RumbleStrip.Website\
AUTH_TYPE=
AUTH_USER=
AUTH_PASSWORD=
LOGON_USER=
REMOTE_USER=
CERT_COOKIE=
CERT_FLAGS=
CERT_ISSUER=
CERT_KEYSIZE=
CERT_SECRETKEYSIZE=
CERT_SERIALNUMBER=
CERT_SERVER_ISSUER=
CERT_SERVER_SUBJECT=
CERT_SUBJECT=
CONTENT_LENGTH=0
CONTENT_TYPE=
GATEWAY_INTERFACE=CGI/1.1
HTTPS=off
HTTPS_KEYSIZE=
HTTPS_SECRETKEYSIZE=
HTTPS_SERVER_ISSUER=
HTTPS_SERVER_SUBJECT=
INSTANCE_ID=2
INSTANCE_META_PATH=/LM/W3SVC/2
LOCAL_ADDR=192.168.1.2
PATH_INFO=/
PATH_TRANSLATED=C:\development\rumble-strip\projects\net-framework\RumbleStrip.Website
QUERY_STRING=&REMOTE_ADDR=192.168.1.5&REMOTE_HOST=192.168.1.5
REMOTE_PORT=54748
REQUEST_METHOD=GET
SCRIPT_NAME=/
SERVER_NAME=192.168.1.2
SERVER_PORT=80
SERVER_PORT_SECURE=0
SERVER_PROTOCOL=HTTP/1.1
SERVER_SOFTWARE=Microsoft-IIS/10.0
URL=/
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL=max-age=0
HTTP_CONNECTION=keep-alive
HTTP_ACCEPT=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING=gzip, deflate, sdch
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE=en-US,en;q=0.8
HTTP_COOKIE=_ga=GA1.1.420021277.1447377172
HTTP_HOST=192.168.1.2
HTTP_USER_AGENT=Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0.2; HTC One Build/LRX22G) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.76 Mobile Safari/537.36
HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS=1
HTTP_DNT=1
IS_LOGIN_PAGE=1
```

Comment: 1. I have tried on actual devices (3 different Android versions now, 5.1, 6.0 and unknown, but older than 5.0). It's worth noting that Marshmallow works (added to OP).  2. Code is deployed on a server on the local network.  3. I have not, I can give this a go but I think it's unlikely to help since the problem seems to be something about the response being received rather than the request being sent.

Comment: I tried this on my local machine using my Android device (5.0.2) over wireless using Chrome (46.0.2490.76).  I was able to download the file from there to my device.  Here is the MVC controller method I used:

`public FileContentResult Index()
  {
   return File(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\temp\profile.jpg"), "application/octet-stream", "profile.jpg");
  }`

Comment: Are you able to post the headers from your response?

Comment: Updated the answer so the response format is more legible.

Comment: Thanks, sadly I can reproduce the same response and still get nothing downloaded.  Oh well.

Comment: I think your best bet then is to create an Android app using Xamarin.  That way you can have a debugger connected on both sides.  I've had to do that debugging communications between my mobile app and web api.

If you need a demo application I'd be happy to whip up a basic app which can do just that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, if you're curious I stumbled across the answer to this and have posted it.

Comment: That's great and good information.  I was happy to help.  :)

In now knowing that bit of information I'll probably right up a test app just to see if a Xamarin app would work fine compared to chrome or if the problem is systemic to Android's DNS resolution.  When I get around to trying that out I'll post the results back here.